# How to take an entire column of a database and turn it into a String array?

Tags: android, arrays, string, sqlite, cursor

I'm trying to take an entire column from a table in my DB and store all the entries into a String array Below you have my code:

```
    public Cursor fetchAllBarcodeEntries(){
    return db.query(BARCODE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_BARCODE_ID, KEY_BARCODE_NUMBER, KEY_BARCODE_PRODUCT, KEY_BARCODE_PRODUCT_DESC}, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

I'm calling and using the function like this:

```
    Cursor c = dbAdapter.fetchAllBarcodeEntries();

    for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
        stringArray[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE_PRODUCT);
    }
```

This is part of the error log that I'm getting

```
01-26 23:15:02.434: E/AndroidRuntime(787): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Any help would this would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: The answer is [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938847/android-transform-each-column-of-a-cursor-into-a-string-array

Comment: Just to explain that error. The bit where it says `Index -1 requested` is actually referring to the 'row' index. When you perform a query using a `Cursor` the row index is always set to be before the first record returned, i.e., -1 (the first record returned has index of 0). As has been shown in the answers, before attempting to retrieve anything via the cursor you have to call `moveToFirst()` or `moveToNext()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938847/android-transform-each-column-of-a-cursor-into-a-string-array)

```
ArrayList<String> columnArray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> columnArray2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> columnArray3 = new ArrayList<String>();
if(mCursor.moveToFirst()!=null){
  do{ 
    columnArray1.add(mCursor.getString(COLUM_INDEX1));
    columnArray2.add(mCursor.getString(COLUM_INDEX2));
    columnArray3.add(mCursor.getString(COLUM_INDEX3));
  } while (mCursor.moveToNext()!=null);
}
```

Afterwards you can convert the ArrayList into a String array:

```
String[] colStrArr1 = (String[]) columnArray1.toArray(new String[columnArray1.size()]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I've just noticed something. By using that...I seem to lose the last entry in the table. I have 4 entries and the final array size I get is only 3...Am I missing something? LE: It's not taking my FIRST database entry, and only taking the last 3.

Comment: Edited (but sorry, I am writing from home, can't check)

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of c.getColumnIndex(). It is probably returning -1 because the given column (dbAdapter.KEY_BARCODE_PRODUCT) does not exist in that table, possibly due to an error on your database.

Also, what's Toast.LENGTH_SHORT doing there?
It seems something is missing from the code you posted...

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this below:

```
Cursor c = dbAdapter.fetchAllBarcodeEntries();

int columnCnt = c.getColumnCount ();

String[] stringArray = new String[columnCnt];
c.moveTofirst();



    for(int i = 0; i < columnCnt ; i++){

        stringArray[i] = c.getString(i);
}
```

Note: I don't have IDE handy, there may be syntax errors.